# Запрос на SQL с динамически меняющимися условиями выборки

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть запрос SQL. Параметры выборки будут всегда одинаковы, но  условия выборки могут быть разными.

Требуется эти условия сохранять в БД и затем подставлять, по необходимости, в  запрос. Как сделать это, допустим, через PHP я себе могу представить (просто выбираем из таблицы нужное условие и присоединяем к строчке запроса).

Можно ли это реализовать на SQL? Т.е. вернуть данные от стандартного запроса с присоединенными условиями, выбранными из таблицы БД?

Comment: Есть какие-то более конкретные пожелания/требования/примеры, в каком виде должны храниться условия и как они должны работать? Пока на вопрос в таком виде можно ответить только "да, можно".

Comment: Такие вопросы лучше дополнять небольшими примерами данных и того, что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно.

Составить SQL запрос можно так же как и в PHP, надо выбрать из таблицы нужное условие и присоединить к строчке запроса. Любой SQL клиент в этом контексте мало чем отличается от PHP клиента, разве что синтаксисом конкантинации строчных значений.

В PL/SQL воспользуйтесь динамическим запросом:

```
declare
    sqlStmt varchar2 (32000); 
    result <тип ресультата>;
    whereCond varchar2 (4000);  
begin
    sqlStmt := 'select ... from ... where ';
    execute immediate sqlStmt||whereCond
    into result; 
end;
```

Но всё вышеизложенное абсолютно не нужно для решения задачи как в вопросе. Надо просто составить **только один** SQL запрос учитывая условия ранее сохранённые в БД.

Answer (score 3):

Ну например... есть таблица

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, val INT);

INSERT INTO test (val)
VALUES (1),(4),(3),(66),(32),(12),(67),(34),(3),(54),(82),(11),(90);
```

Периодически надо в неё делать запрос такого типа:

```
SELECT MIN(val), MAX(val), COUNT(DISTINCT val)
FROM test
WHERE id BETWEEN @min AND @max;
```

Для решения задачи создаём таблицу параметров, в которую мы и будем помещать нужные в данный момент параметры:

```
CREATE TABLE params (mini BIGINT, maxi BIGINT, dt DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

И создаём представление, которое возьмёт текущие нужные нам параметры и вернёт соотв. выборку.

```
CREATE VIEW get_data_from_test
AS
SELECT MIN(val), MAX(val), COUNT(DISTINCT val)
FROM test, (SELECT mini, maxi
            FROM params
            ORDER BY dt DESC
            LIMIT 1) parameters
WHERE id BETWEEN mini AND maxi;
```

Проходит неделя, и нам нужны сведения при значениях параметров 10 и 35. Соответственно мы заносим их в таблицу параметров

```
INSERT INTO params (mini, maxi)
SELECT 10, 35;
```

А затем делаем просто

```
SELECT * 
FROM get_data_from_test;
```

Вуаля! нужные данные на экране.

Само собой, это один из возможных вариантов, простейший. Обычно на месте представления - изрядно навороченная процедура. В которую, в отличие от представления, можно некоторые параметры передать через таблицу, а некоторые напрямую - как явно, так и через пользовательские переменные с предопределённым именем. Но суть от этого меняется мало...

Собственно, это называется "реализация логики на стороне сервера". А текст представления или процедуры пользователю может быть совсем недоступен - данные получи, а как они получаются, по какому алгоритму, не твоё дело.

Comment: А что такое SERIAL у вас? Думал автоикрементый id какой, попробовал на liveSQL - ORA-00902: invalid datatype

Comment: *А что такое SERIAL* Синоним `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE`. Да, специфично для MySQL, пардон...

Comment: Есть ещё пара строк, где MySQL специфичные обороты.